# CanCan not preventing access when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan

Visiting `users/1/edit` when I'm signed in as different user does not raise an AccessDenied error, and I have no idea why:

```
  authorize_resource only: [:edit, :update]
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    can :read, :all
    can :create, User
    can :create, Group

    can :update, User, id: user.id
  end
end
```

If I change `authorize_resource` to `load_and_authorize_resource` then it works as expected. But this should not be relevant, surely?

Comment: Whats your controller's class name?

Comment: It's `UsersController`. My authentication methods are split into SessionsHelper, which is included in `ApplicationController`. The permissions for Groups work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only authorize the user to access edit and update action not the `@user` object

you have to manually authorize the object like this

Try this,

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @user
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :update, @user
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
   redirect_to @user
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't access to `edit` fail then? As it stands, both `get` and `put` allow access when they should not.

Comment: can you please elaborate i can't understand

Comment: did you add this line authorize_resource only => [:edit, :update] check the Readme.doc (after 47th line, where i found this)

Comment: What I mean is, I'm currently using `authorize_resource only [:edit, :update]`. Should this not prevent any access to the edit page and the update action? As it stands, I'm allowed access. Shouldn't `authorize_resource` prevent this access?

Comment: I think i got you now, use `skip_authorize` so you can access the action without any authorization

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issues like you,but for me,I'm using devise with cancan. Therefore ,in my controller, i will put

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except=>[:create]
```

it will authenticate user except the create.

```
def index
    @user = User.all
    authorize! :index, @user
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
end
```

each of your controller function that you want to authorize the access of user, you can do like this, it seems you have to do lots of works by putting every single in the function that you need to authorize instead just using        load_and_authorize_resource, but hope can help u a little from what i have completed.  here is the resource:https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions. If you get an answer and why the load_and_authorize_resource is not working, post to here too :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! As far as I am concerned, authorize_resource should work. I'll try and get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for you (yet) on why this happens, but I encountered essentially the same issue.  My situation was only different in that manually authorizing each action (instead of relying on either "authorize resource" or "load_and_authorize" was the key.

Answer (score 1):

I am running into this issue as well, and here is what I have found.

[If I'm reading the source code right](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L68), during an `:update` action, `load_and_authorize` does a `find_by` to load the resource, then calls `authorize!` on it.  However, I don't see where it authorizes it after the incoming parameters have been applied.  (Someone please correct me if I'm reading this wrong.)

The use case I am seeing this is when someone edits a resource, and in the edit, updates a value in the resource that makes it no longer eligible to pass authorization on save. (Granted, I am setting up the UI to help avoid this situation, but obviously I still want to protect the resource.)   Running a functional test, I was able to set attributes that I expected not to pass authorization on the controller `:update` action, presumably because the check happens before the attributes are parsed.

So far, the way I have worked around it is to call `authorize!` again after I have set the attributes, which means I can't use `update_attributes` since I want to authorize before saving:

```
class FooController < ApplicationControlller

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def update

    # slurp the mass assignable params
    @foo.attributes = params[:foo]

    # set some other params
    @foo.some_other_attr = 'bar'

    # authorize again, now that we have updated the params
    authorize! :update, @foo

    if @foo.save!
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t(...)   
      respond_with(@foo)
    # ...
    end 
  end 
end
```

An alternative is to create a before_filter, load the `@foo` instance yourself, then call authorize as above, but that doesn't really make things much cleaner, IMHO.  It would just save on one authorize! call.

I'm curious as to how others are handling this. I am fairly new to CanCan, so I am presuming I am doing something wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've transitioned my app and the issue went away. I'm not able to replicate it now. I ended up manually loading the objects and calling authorize_resource! which I prefer anyway.